# DataGridView bound with binding list displays blank rows

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, datagridview, sql-server-2012

I have table in my database stored in SQL Server 2012 and through this table I am iterating and adding new object in my binding list. This list is then set as datasource for my `DataGridView`.

As I understand, the `DataGridView` should create columns and fill the rows with data, but when I run the build, I only see blank rows. Their count is matching the count of rows in table and I also debugged with breakpoints so I have determined that I really have my datasource filled with data, but I cannot figure those blank rows out.

This is method I use for creating dataset and filling the binding list

```
public void selectCars()
{
    string connString = @"Data Source=POHJOLA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BlueCars;Integrated Security=True";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Car ORDER BY CarID ASC";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        using (DataSet result = new DataSet())
        {
            adapter.Fill(result);

            foreach (DataRow row in result.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                carsList.Add(new Car(Convert.ToInt32(row[0]), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), Convert.ToDecimal(row[4]),Convert.ToInt32(row[5]),row[6].ToString(),row[7].ToString() ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my initialization

```
public managerCarForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    selectCars();
    carsGrid.DataSource = carsList;
}
```

Also I should probably add, that I created columns manually in designer and set datanameproperty to parameters of the car class

I am not getting any exception or error here..

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this?  I also have a DataGridView that reads my DataSource (breakpoints confirm the data is in there), it creates the columns correctly, and the correct number of rows, but they're all blank.  Wondering if you found out why.  Mine is Windows Form, so no DataBinding() statement.

Comment: How is your `Car` class defined? I was having exactly the same problematic behavior in VB.NET (DataGridView loaded with a List of objects, blank rows displayed), and turned out that the problem was that my class members were defined as public fields and it seems that public fields are not allowed for binding. Changing the public fields to public properties solved my problem. Thanks to **francezu13k50**'s answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27786963/8133067

Answer (score 1):

Normally this happens when you have manually added the columns in design time.
Or you have `AutoGenerateColumns = false;`

If you use `AutoGenerateColumns = true;` the columns will be/should be auto generated.

To solve this:
Right click on the grid -> Edit Columns.

Go to property: DataPropertyName

Set that to the variable name that you bind to (the table column name in your case).
(You say you have done that, but the value here should exactly match what you have in your list. I have made a DTO class and via a loop I have populated a List of my own and set the names to match the properties of that DTO. This should solve it for you.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came across the exact same problem in VB.

I Found out that the solution was this:

(I´ll just write my code in VB you can translate it).

Before setting the `DataSource` of the grid, you should `Clear` the grid out.

```
carsGrid.DataSource = Nothing
carsGrid.Rows.Clear()
carsGrid.Columns.Clear()
```

Then set your grid `DataSource` as usual. In My case:

```
carsGrid.DataSource = GetEmptyObject._Get()
```

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
                foreach (DataRow row in result.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        carsList.Add(new Car(Convert.ToInt32(row[0]), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), Convert.ToDecimal(row[4]),Convert.ToInt32(row[5]),row[6].ToString(),row[7].ToString() ));
                    }
```

Please check your carList by applying a breakpoint after foreach loop to verify it contains at least a single data row. And also check your query.

If your application is an ASP.NET 
try to modify your code as below..

```
public managerCarForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    selectCars();
    carsGrid.DataSource = carsList;
    carsGrid.Databind();

}
```

Comment: if this is an ASP.NET form..
carsGrid.DataSource = carsList;
Add this line after above line
carsGrid.Databind();

Comment: this is Windows Forms - Databind() is not in my context